# PyQt Get specific value in ListWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, maya

I am new to python and pyqt/pyside ...

i make customwidget class consist of 2 label (title & desc) which is example instance to add to Listwidget later ...

here is the complete clean code (pyside maya)

```
import PySide.QtCore as qc
import PySide.QtGui as qg

class CustomQWidget (qg.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(CustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.textQVBoxLayout = qg.QVBoxLayout()
        self.titleLabel    = qg.QLabel()
        self.description  = qg.QLabel()
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.titleLabel)
        self.textQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.description)
        self.setLayout(self.textQVBoxLayout)
    def setTitle (self, text):
        self.titleLabel.setText(text)
    def setDescription (self, text):
        self.description.setText(text)

class example_ui(qg.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        qg.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.myQListWidget = qg.QListWidget(self)
        self.myQListWidget.currentItemChanged.connect(self.getTitleValue)
        self.myQListWidget.setGeometry(qc.QRect(0,0,200,300))
        # make instance customwidget item (just one)------
        instance_1 = CustomQWidget()
        instance_1.setTitle('First title')
        instance_1.setDescription('this is a sample desc')
        myQListWidgetItem = qg.QListWidgetItem(self.myQListWidget)
        myQListWidgetItem.setSizeHint(instance_1.sizeHint())
        self.myQListWidget.addItem(myQListWidgetItem)
        self.myQListWidget.setItemWidget(myQListWidgetItem, instance_1)
    def getTitleValue(self,val):
       # i make assume something like below but didnt work
       # print (self.myQListWidget.currentItem.titleLabel.text()
       return 0
dialog = example_ui()
dialog.show()
```

now at `getTitleValue` function how do i get Title and desc value when i change selection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remember that the list items and corresponding widgets are not the same. Luckily, `QListWidget` tracks them and gives you access to the displayed widget if you provide the list item:

```
class example_ui(qg.QDialog):
    def getTitleValue(self,val):
        # parameter val is actually the same as self.myQListWidget.currentItem
        selected_widget = self.myQListWidget.itemWidget(val)
        print selected_widget.titleLabel.text()       
        return 0
```

Side note: I had to add a main loop in order for the app to be executed at all:

```
import sys # to give Qt access to parameters
# ... class definitions etc. ... 
app = qg.QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = example_ui()
dialog.show()
exec_status = app.exec_() # main loop
```

Comment: Thanks Sanyok for your time, i understand now,  Note : i run the code inside maya and just fine, that would need a main loop (like you type) if want to run directly from python. thanks